# How to break one observation down to several observation?

Tags: r, text

Here is my data

```
title <- c("title1","title2")
text <- c("Mr.A.Speech1.\\nMr.B.Speech2.\\nMr.C.Speech3\\n","Mrs.D.Speech4.\\nMs.E.Speech5.\\n")
df<- data.frame(title, text)
```

I want each speech as a row labeled with title:

```
     Title    Name.     Text
1.   title1   Mr.A      Speech1.
2.   title1   Mr.B      Speech2.
3.   title1   Mr.C      Speech3.
4.   title1   Mrs.D     Speech4.
5.   title1   Ms.E      Speech5.
```

I can breakdown only one observation of text, for example, to breakdown

```
name <- unlist(str_extract_all(df$text,"\\bM(?:rs?|s)\\.\\s[:upper:]{1,20}\\s?c?'?-?[:upper:]{1,20}\\s?o?f?\\s?|The\\sSPEAKER|The\\sPRESIDING\\s" ))
##breakdown speeches and remove content before the first name
pattern = "\\bM(?:rs?|s)\\.\\s[:upper:]{1,20}\\s?c?'?-?[:upper:]{1,20}\\s?o?f?\\s?|The\\sSPEAKER|The\\sPRESIDING\\s"
df$text1 <- str_replace_all( df$text, pattern, "XXXX")
df$text2 <- gsub("^.*?XXXX","XXXX",df$text1)
dfa <- df[which(grepl("XXXX",df$text2)), ]

speech1 <- unlist(strsplit(df$text2, "XXXX"))
speech2 <- speech1[-1]
Text <- gsub("[\\]", " ", speech2)
```

How can I add the title label for each row and apply the breakdown for the whole column? Thanks!

Comment: The code that you have doesn't work for me. `nametest` returns `character(0)` and consequently `dftest` has no rows.

Comment: I am sorry and you are right. I just put my code (very lengthy) for my real dataset in the question. I used df1 <- dfa %>% 
  separate_rows(text2, sep ="XXXX")%>% 
  filter(text2 != "")  and get the results. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but regex is not my strong suit

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(text,sep = "\\\\n") %>%
  filter(text != "") %>% 
  separate(col = text,into = c("name","aux","text"),sep = "\\.") %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(name,aux,sep = ".")) %>% 
  select(-aux)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  title  name  text   
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  
1 title1 Mr.A  Speech1
2 title1 Mr.B  Speech2
3 title1 Mr.C  Speech3
4 title2 Mrs.D Speech4
5 title2 Ms.E  Speech5
```